# How to get the PID of a VB3 process running in Win7?

Tags: process, cmd, pid

I tried to use the tasklist command in cmd but it was not listed in there.
I also notice that the process is a little indented in task manager together with another process called wowexec.exe.
Any way to get the PID of the process? For reasons of hex editing.

Answer (score 0):

`wmic` is nice for running sql-like queries to get the information you need.  Replace `wowexec` in the following example with something resembling the task name of your VB3 process.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic process where "name like '%%wowexec%%'" get processid /format:list') do set "PID=%%I"
```

Something like that is what you would put in a batch script.

If you're just running this from a `cmd` console, use `%I` instead of `%%I`, and `do @echo %I` instead of `do set` etc.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %I in ('wmic process where "name like '%%wowexec%%'" get processid /format:list') do @echo %I
```

**Note:** The double percents around `wowexec` signify literal percent symbols, a SQL syntax wildcard character.  `wowexec` is not a variable, but a literal string.